# Show that if $n$ is not a multiple of $2$ then it is not a multiple of $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, quantifiers

I was trying to do this question and got a bit confused, am I to use quantifiers?

I came up with an answer that *seems* right but probably isn't.

Show that if $n$ is not a multiple of $2$ then it is not a multiple of $6$:

$$
\exists n \forall x [(n \neq 2x) \land (n \neq 6x)]
$$

So I am trying to say that for some $n$, $n$ is not a multiple of $2$ **and** therefore is not a multiple of $6$.

Am I correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the math (which should be obvious) or about how to do the problem using symbolic logic. Ie how to "translate" it.  If I'm reading it right, your statement says there is a number that isn't a multiple of 2 or 6.  I think you want $\forall n \forall (n\not = 2x \implies \forall x (n\not = 6x) $ or maybe $\forall n (\exists x n=6x)  \lor (\not \exists x n=2x) $.  Maybe.

Comment: I don't see how your statement is an answer.  You don't explain *why* it is; you just seem to be trying to repeat what is said.

Comment: Ok then I must have completely misunderstood what they question wanted me to do, thank you for clearing that up

Comment: I'm not sure whether you misunderstood or not.  I'm willing to believe *I* do not understand exactly what you are asking.  Mathematically the answer is simple as topological cat answered.  But if the exercise is to write and prove it using symbolic logic  this can be quite involved and technical.

Comment: The question began with *using either a contrapositive proof or a proof by contradiction, show that..* I just didn't understand what it meant, but @Topological cat helped me make more sense of it

Comment: If that was the question then topological cat's answer is a correct one.

Comment: The formula with logical symbols says there is something which is neither a multiple of $2$ nor a multiple of $6$. It has little or no connection with the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know I was doing a few questions where I had to use quantifiers so when I was asked this question I was confused and tried to use quantifiers where they didn't belong @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is a multiple of $6$ then $n = 6k = 2(3k)$ is a multiple of $2$. This is proof by contrapositive

Comment: So that's all I need for the answer and mine is completely wrong?

Comment: dunno. I don't see your answer.. you just wrote something unrelated (don't see where you are going with it)

Comment: I wrote $\exists n \forall x [(n \neq 2x) \land (n \neq 6x)]$ as my answer

Comment: yes I don't see where you are going with it

Comment: Almost every mamal is homeomorphic to a cat, what are you really?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling humans aren't even homeomorphic to each other. Boys have $2$ holes and girls have $3$ down there

Comment: The urethra is also a hole, they are homeomorphic.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling how are you counting them? I am counting: urethra, anus. Are there any more that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What *is* the question?  Is it 1) show that if n is not a multiple of 2 then it is not a multiple of 6.  2) to write "if n ...." in symbolic logic.  Or 3) to write and prove the statement using only symbolic logic.  The correct answer depends on knowing what the question is.

Comment: *Using either a contrapositive proof or a proof by contradiction, show that..* @fleablood

Comment: Ok, how are you counting them on females? I'm pretty sure the third is just a cavity that could be topologically undone.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling vagina, urethra, anus. Please elaborate, how may we topologically undo any?

Comment: One of those isn't a hole, it's a cavity, you can't go through it from one place and go out another, and in fact the nostrils and ears are in fact holes.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling yes I'm aware about nostrils and ears, I was talking about the lower part. Let's settle this down. If we are talking about the whole body, are males and females homeomorphic?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling it turns out that this topic has been well discussed before. Apparently Gamow in "one, two, three infinity" mentions that humans are donuts. There seems to be a consensus that males and females are homeomorphic. I think I need to post this as a question and maybe get a thorough answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove the statement $\color\red{2\nmid n}\implies\color\green{6\nmid n}$.

Instead, prove the equivalent statement $\neg(\color\green{6\nmid n})\implies\neg(\color\red{2\nmid n})$.

---

$\neg(6\nmid n)\implies$

$6\mid n\implies$

$\exists{k\in\mathbb{Z}}:[n=6\cdot k]\implies$

$\exists{k\in\mathbb{Z}}:[n=2\cdot(3\cdot k)]\implies$

$\exists{m\in\mathbb{Z}}:[n=2\cdot m]\implies$

$2\mid n\implies$

$\neg(2\nmid n)$